# startup script yum install fails with "signature could not be verified for google-cloud-sdk"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I reran the startup script using following command:
`sudo google_metadata_script_runner --script-type startup`

All the `yum install` commands are failing with following error:

```
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: Retrieving key from https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/cloud-sdk-el7-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno -1] repomd.xml signature could not be verified for google-cloud-sdk
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: Trying other mirror.
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url:  One of the configured repositories failed (Google Cloud SDK),
```

Any idea how I could fix this while instance provisioning or any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I have found this on google, not sure if this helps but maybe you can try it out anyway.

1) Disable Caching in yum config `/etc/yum.conf`:

`http_caching=none`

2) Delete tmp yum files:
`rm -r /var/tmp/yum*`

3) restart machines

4) cleanup yum:

```
yum clean metadata  
yum clean all  
yum update
```

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to reproduce the issue on my end. It would be helpful if you could share the information below:

1. What is the exact OS you are using here.
2. What happens when you are trying to run the scripts manually after VM starts.
3. Can you please share the sample script without the confidential information or credentials.

Though I have not tested this, the error can happen due to yum  not having  enough cached data to continue. And the solution can be found on the public: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/yum-doesn-t-have-enough-cached-data-to-continue/m-p/220862

Comment: properly use list to display your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this same error on a Docker build.

Google Cloud's (latest) [repo configuration](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#rpm) is as follows:

```
[google-cloud-cli]
name=Google Cloud CLI
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/cloud-sdk-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=0
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg
       https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
```

Our Dockerfile yum repo configuration had to be corrected from `repo_gpgcheck=1` to `repo_gpgcheck=0` and then the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

For me running `yum-config-manager --disable google-cloud-sdk` solved it. I got this from the error message that I got:

```
...
4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
    will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
    again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable google-cloud-sdk
    or
        subscription-manager repos --disable=google-cloud-sdk
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone's facing same issue with apt. Can try --

```
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
```